# argument not passed correctly to the remote bash script

Tags: bash, shell

So I've got this script that runs on rhel 5.8 and what it does is that it reads two arguments, should be dates in yyyy-mm-dd format, and fires a script on a remote server, sunOS 5.10. In both sides the shell I'm using is /bin/bash

The part of the code that's not working as expected is the below:

```
...
CC="IE"
read -p "Please provide start date (format yyyy-mm-dd): " STARTDATE
read -p "Please provide end date (format yyyy-mm-dd): " ENDDATE
echo ""
echo "Start Date provided :" $STARTDATE
echo "End date provided :" $ENDDATE
echo ""

echo "Executing query on the remote side, please wait..."
ssh -t user@rem_host '/tmp/rem_script.sh '${CC}' '${STARTDATE}' '${ENDDATE}' ' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

What I get when set -x on the local host is the following

```
+ read -p 'Please provide start date (format yyyy-mm-dd): ' STARTDATE
Please provide start date (format yyyy-mm-dd): 2014-05-08
+ read -p 'Please provide end date (format yyyy-mm-dd): ' ENDDATE
Please provide end date (format yyyy-mm-dd): 2014-05-09
+ echo ''

+ echo 'Start Date provided :' 2014-05-08
Start Date provided : 2014-05-08
+ echo 'End date provided :' 2014-05-09
End date provided : 2014-05-09
+ echo ''

+ echo 'Executing query on the remote side, please wait...'
Executing query on the remote side, please wait...
+ ssh -t user@rem_host '/tmp/rem_script.sh IE 2014-05-08 2014-05-09 '
```

But what I see on the remote side being executed is the following:

```
user   730   688   0 10:30:31 pts/2       0:00 bash -c /tmp/rem_script.sh IE 2014-05-08 2014-05
```

Can anyone please tell me why the last date is being chopped off? How can I correct this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's probably `ps` that's not displaying it in full (i.e. you don't have a problem.) (`cat /proc/script_pid/cmdline` on the remote server to verify.)

Comment: Do you expect to get values if you put variable in `' '` single one.. try and put in double, everywhere!

Comment: @Jord He's ending the quote before putting in the variable.

Comment: What `ps` options are you using? Use `ww` to get the full command line, otherwise it limits the size to the terminal width.

Comment: Can't be because if I run the remote script on the remote end with the same arguments it runs fine, producing a 2Mb report file, but the report I get when running it from my side has a single sql error. Tried also with a longer path and ps was showing more chars, everything apart from my last date :)

Comment: yep, my bad.. taking back!